# Make an "auto switch" input?

Tags: geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

Here is my problem:
I have a simulation system that creates a flow of points with the help of a *Distribute Points on Faces* node and the points are moving up with a *Set Position* Z offset.

By default, the *Distribute Points on Faces* node spawns points every frame making a constant stream of points going up.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have a switch linked to the input so the user could check the switch to ON and then have the system uncheck the switch back to OFF state exactly one frame later.

I know the user could keyframe the checkbox of the switch from OFF to ON and OFF again but I'm trying to make something automatic that would be triggered by the user and one frame later automatically switch it back again, so the user could easily spawn a single point multiple times with a single keyframe.

**How could I achieve this?**

Image 1: My current system

Image 2: Result if the switch is checked ON

Image 3: Intended result made artificially by keyframing the switch OFF-ON-OFF

[image: My current system]
[image: Result if the switch is checked ON]
[image: Intended result made artificially by keyframing the switch OFF-ON-OFF]

Comment: i think this should be possible by a python script driver for the switch.

Comment: This would not be optimal in my situation. but yes it would be possible.

but i think it would also be possible if i manage to find a way to change the state of the "true" and "false" of the switch, if the switch toggle between a 0 and a 1 and each of theses are flickering from 0-1 each frame the toggle would have a similar effect, but i can't figure out how to do it...

Comment: i cannot think of another way toggle an input switch...